# Current domain and replacing domain

Tags: apex, visualforce, site.com, custom-domain

Current domain set up for the organization reflects the organization's prior name.

I was told that each org can have one domain, and would like to inquire as to what the best way to do it is, whether it is to go through support to change the name, or to create a new domain and migrate everything over. In the case of the latter, after clicking through the org, 
I cannot seem to find the correct place to create a new domain.

Comment: Did you mean that you want to change your force.com site name, or that you have a custom url that you are redirecting to your force.com site that you want to change?

Comment: You can contact Salesforce support to change the domain name.

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Interesting. The documentation is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is still not possible to do by yourself, on page 4 of the Winter ’16 [Force.com Sites Implementation
Guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/17/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_portal_implementation_guide.pdf), there is a warning that says:

> Warning:  You can't modify your 
>   Force.com domain name after you have registered it.

You could try contacting salesforce to see if they can change it for you, or even if you don't change your force.com domain, if your site is in a production environment, you could register a domain through [one of the many registrars](https://www.icann.org/registrar-reports/accreditation-qualified-list.html) and redirect it to your force.com site.

There's an overview of how to do it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653&language=en_US).

Comment: Do you have an affiliation with namecheap? I might remove the suggestion or recommend other alternatives so you seem like a more neutral source.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No, I don't have an affiliation with them, it's just what I use.